# \cs_new:Nn counts the letters in the tail of its first argument, doesn’t it?

Tags: expl3, latex3

Citing from interface3.pdf:

```
\cs_new:Nn <function> {<code>}
```

“...the number of `<parameters>` is detected automatically from the function signature.”

I believe that `<parameters>` should be “parameters” and “function” should indeed be `<function>`. Or even better:

The number of parameters is determined by the `<function>` name, where the number of letters after the colon is counted. E.g. `\cs_new:Nn \my_command:NNabcde {}` is assumed to have 7 parameters.

Can someone confirm that?

Comment: I am seriously only 85% sure.

Comment: Actually `\cs_new:Nn \my_command:NNabcde {}` is invalid (try it). You can suggest documentation improvements at the [LaTeX3 github repo](https://github.com/latex3/latex3). I think it's not appropriate as a question here...

Comment: `This is a coding error.

Functions defined through \cs_new:Nn must have a signature consisting of only
normal arguments 'N' and 'n'. To define variants use \cs_generate_variant:Nn
and to define other functions use \cs_new:Npn.` This is way more informative than the documentation! @PhelypeOleinik

Comment: @RobertSiemer About your second question, page 1 of `interface3` says that "`:` separates the _name_ of the function from the _argument specifier_", and later in the same paragraph it says that the list of _argument specifiers_ is the _signature_, so the sentence in the documentation is correct (maybe the markup could be improved), but it's using previously defined terminology. Suggestions are very welcome in the GitHub repo, however I think this is not exactly a question here, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a suggestion for documentation improvement, which should be filed at the LaTeX3 GitHub repository.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Good that you mention that paragraph, because I was just reading it over and over while redacting the question. You might notice that it actually specifies the _argument specifier_ as being equal to the _signature_. It later also says that the name ends with a colon in some cases. But the _name_ is defined as ending before the colon!?—So yes, the markup could be improved, as the whole section could be.

Comment: @RobertSiemer Documentation is notoriously hard to write, as who wrote the code usually has a very different vision than who will read it, but is usually who ends up having to write it. Again, suggestions are welcome.